# Change stellar quickstart docker from ephemeral to persistent without shutting it down

Tags: stellar-core, docker, postgres

I made the mistake of running my Stellar instances with the `-v "/home/Drew/XCoin:/Drew/XCoin"` flags instead of the required `-v "/home/Drew/stellar:/opt/stellar"`flags that Stellar recommends on the their site. Thus, I thought that each of my 4 instances were running on persistent mode but I soon learned that they were on ephemeral and deleting all the states. If I navigate to an instances port `11626/info` I find that all history archives have failed because the instance is in ephemeral mode:

```
         "vs" : {
            "failure" : 937,
            "success" : 0
         }
      },
```

Currently, I have 4 nodes running the entire quickstart stack with a custom network name and they're connected together. There have been too many user transactions on the network to consider wiping it. With the current setup, instances are eating up upwards of 10GBs of storage a day from all the transactions because they can't archive them to an S3 bucket.

**Question**: How can I make my nodes persistent without spinning them down? Is it possible to spin up another instance with the proper settings and have it catchup/replay the network history and archive that?

Comment: Ephemeral mode command `$ docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --testnet` ; Persistent mode `docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" -v "/home/scott/stellar:/opt/stellar" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --testnet
`. So, the difference is a mounting volume `-v "/home/scott/stellar:/opt/stellar"`. Maybe take a try with this guide: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302178/how-can-i-add-a-volume-to-an-existing-docker-container